# How to detect main structure contour by detecting straight lines

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I'm trying to detect main structures of many `floor plan` pictures by detecting straight lines and edges, with reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452491/opencv-python-houghlinesp-strange-results/36453133#36453133).

[image]

The example above is one example I need to deal with, is it possible to get main structure by detecting lines with `opencv HoughLinesP` from it? Thanks for your help at advance.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_lines(lines_in):
    if cv2.__version__ < '3.0':
        return lines_in[0]
    return [l[0] for l in lines]

img = cv2.imread('./test.jpg', 1)
img_gray = gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cannied = cv2.Canny(img_gray, threshold1=50, threshold2=200, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cannied, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=80, minLineLength=30, maxLineGap=10)

for line in get_lines(lines):
    leftx, boty, rightx, topy = line
    cv2.line(img, (leftx, boty), (rightx,topy), (255, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imwrite('./lines.png', img)
cv2.imwrite('./canniedHouse.png', cannied)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Results:

> lines.png

[image: lines.png]

> canniedHouse.png

[image: canniedHouse.png]

Other references:

[How to get the external contour of a floorplan in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366439/how-to-get-the-external-contour-of-a-floorplan-in-python)

[Floor Plan Edge Detection - Image Processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532473/floor-plan-edge-detection-image-processing/19549678)

Comment: You have code. What was the result?

Comment: I update result images, in which lines are not visible, please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an approach

- Convert image to grayscale
- Adaptive threshold to obtain binary image
- Perform morphological transformations to smooth image
- Create horizontal kernel and detect horizontal lines
- Create vertical kernel and detect vertical lines

---

After converting to grayscale, we adaptive threshold to obtain a binary image

```
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

[image]

From here we perform morphological transformations to smooth the image

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
```

[image]

Now we create a horizontal kernel with `cv2.getStructuringElement()` and detect horizontal lines

```
# Find horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (35,2))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)
```

[image]

Similarly, we create a vertical kernel and detect vertical lines

```
# Find vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,35))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)
```

[image]

Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (35,2))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)

# Find vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,35))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

If you wanted to just find the external contour you can find contours after the morphological close operation

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is much better. Sorry, I have one more question, do you know how to create a mask to remove text from it? such as `01, 02, ... 07, 电梯厅` etc.

Comment: I can't think of a robust way to do it but a potential method would be to find contours and filter using contour area